# Magnetizing current in switching converter

Tags: transformer, converter

I have a question about the magnetizing current in a forward switching converter (image from "[ON Semiconductor: Am improved 2-switch forward converter application](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND378-D.PDF)").

[image: forward converter]

From the picture it looks like there is a finite current in the primary, when the switch Q1 is off. My question is, how is that possible, since the primary is made out of a single wire ? How can you physically have a current in an open wire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That picture is incorrect for anything other than what it is intended for i.e. to demonstrate that you need to reset the flux in an inductor or transformer.

What happens in reality with the circuit shown is that the energy built up (by the rising current) creates a high voltage when the MOSFET turns off and destroys it. They are using this circuit as a "device" to explain the problem.

If you'd shown the full picture and read the subsequent pages you might have made more sense of it: -

[image]

Comment: So, two questions then: A. Is there a current in the primary in the OFF state ? B. Does the current grow in steps like that due to build-up of some sort of permanent magnetization in the core which eventually leads to saturation ?

Comment: All the energy contained is likely to destroy the MOSFET and therefore reset the transformer and then the story is complete after one cycle. If they put a reverse diode across the primary then the current would be largely held constant when the MOSFET was off and would lead to core saturation after a few cycles.